# Smalltalk custom buttons for Dialog

Tags: dialog, smalltalk, visualworks

Is there a way to customize the buttons for Dialog?

Dialog confirm has two buttons (yes/no), but I would like to change the value of the buttons to something else other than (yes/no).

I have been looking for ways to do this, but the given Dialog methods are very limited in terms of having customizable buttons.

Comment: Which Smalltalk are you using? Squeak/Pharo or rather VisualWorks, VA Smalltalk or Dolphin, or?

Comment: @Tobias I'm working with VisualWorks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dialog choose: 'What is your choice?'
    labels: #('Red' 'Black')
    values: #(#red #black)
    default: #red
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have access to a VisualWorks environment, but I seem to recall something along the lines of `Dialog#choose:from:values:` where you can pass in the dialog text, any button texts and the associated values, respectively. (There may be a few more arguments as well.)

Just browse the `Dialog` class (and its hierarchy) and you should be able to find such methods.

If no such method exists, it should be fairly easy to roll your own. It's Smalltalk, after all.